# Why is rendered text different sizes on Chrome and Firefox even when using HTML reset?

Tags: css, html, cross-browser, font-size

All, I understood that setting font-size: 100% on the HTML root element, along with an HTML5 reset and rem units, should cause text to render at the same size on different browsers.

However I see larger rendered text on Firefox than on Chrome on OS X. Here's a test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var mWidth = $('#test').width();
            alert("width is " + mWidth);
        });
      </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://reset5.googlecode.com/hg/reset.min.css" />
      <style>
        html {font-size: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; font-family: Georgia;}
        h1 {display: inline; padding: 0;margin: 0; font-size: 2rem;}
      </style>
      <title>Font Size Test</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <h1 id="test">Testing that font size 100% is the same in Chrome as in Firefox.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

To see it work you have to make your browser window wide enough to display the full line of text. You should see a difference in the reported width as well as visually you should see that the text is larger in Firefox.

- I'm using Google's HTML5 reset, which sets font-size to 100% on the HTML element. I also set it myself to 100%.
- I've set the font-family to be the same.
- I'm using rem units, which should base the font size on the root HTML element.
- Both browsers are set to view at actual size (no zoom).

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each browser has a different translation of what 100% means. Especially IE but also on others. The only way to get truly the same size is to use pixels as your unit of measurement. Then you know it will be consistent.

Comment: Except on machines where the pixel size is drastically different, for instance on ultra-high-res phones, then one "browser-pixel" may mean two or more device pixels.

Comment: Retina devices don't take pixel measurements in css literally. They render as they would on a non-retina screen. Just sharper! But their relative size to the rest of the layout is the same. It's all relative after all.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting html font size to 100%? That means the browser uses *the font size in its user settings!*

For instance, if the user sets IE9's default font size to "extra large", then the 100% means extra large. That is all.